# Shopee RefreshAccessToken always return Error param

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token, shopee

i've tried to get a new token, by running shopee open api RefreshAccessToken with php curl,
but the result always give me error param code.

from this documentation : https://open.shopee.com/documents/v2/OpenAPI%202.0%20Overview?module=87&type=2

```
<?php
      $partner_id   = ...partnerid;
      $partner_key  = ...partnerkey;
      $timest       = time();
      $shop_id      =  ...shopid;
      $refresh_token = ...refresh_token;
      $host         = 'https://partner.shopeemobile.com';
      $path         = '/api/v2/auth/access_token/get';
      $base_string  = sprintf("%s%s%s",$partner_id,$path,$timest);
      $sign         = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $key, false);

      $url  = $host.$path.sprintf("?timestamp=%s&partner_id=%s&sign=%s",$timest,$partner_id,$sign);   
      
        $data = array( 
        'shop_id' => $shop_id,
        'refresh_token:' => $refresh_token,
        'partner_id:' => $partner_id,
        );

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,    
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        // echo $response;
      
?>
```

and the result is

```
{"error":"error_param","message":"error params","request_id":"b61938142425d13e72292xf3b645d62b"}
```

where did my code goes wrong, please help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't work with php, but in python i solved converted type str to int in shop_id and partner_id

```
body = {
    'code': code,
    'shop_id': int(shop_id),
    'partner_id': int(partner_id),
}
```

follow my full code

```
def get_token_shop_level(code, partner_id, partner_key, shop_id):
    timest = int(time.time())

    body = {
        'code': code,
        'shop_id': int(shop_id),
        'partner_id': int(partner_id),
    }

    host = 'https://partner.test-stable.shopeemobile.com'
    path = '/api/v2/auth/token/get'
    base_string = f'{partner_id}{path}{timest}'

    partner_key = partner_key.encode()
    base_string = base_string.encode()

    sign = hmac.new(partner_key, base_string, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    url = host + path + f'?partner_id={partner_id}&timestamp={timest}&sign={sign}'

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    resp = requests.post(url, json=body, headers=headers)
    ret = json.loads(resp.content)
    access_token = ret.get('access_token')
    refresh_token = ret.get('refresh_token')

    return access_token, refresh_token
```

Comment: You haven't given a PHP answer.  The only way this might help the OP is to explain your answer

Comment: This solved my issue. In PHP, you should use `(int) $shop_id` and `(int) $partner_id`  (or `intval()`, if you prefer) since the json_encode will turn those values into strings otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $partner_id   = ...partnerid;
  $partner_key  = ...partnerkey;
  $timest       = time();
  $shop_id      =  ...shopid;
  $refresh_token = ...refresh_token;
  $host         = 'https://partner.shopeemobile.com';
  $path         = '/api/v2/auth/access_token/get';
  $base_string  = sprintf("%s%s%s",$partner_id,$path,$timest);
  $sign         = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $key, false);
```

your $sign is wrong.. should be

```
$sign         = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string,  $partner_key, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in both @SungALy and @Davin Kho, check your code again,
As the error suggested you have an error on your POST data parameters,

```
$data = array( 
        'shop_id' => $shop_id,
        'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
        'partner_id' => $partner_id,
        );
$data = json_encode($data);
```

remove the colon on the array name and convert to JSON before passing as pointed by @SungALy

and $key in

```
$sign         = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $key, false);
```

must be $partner_key

```
$sign         = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $partner_key, false);
```

pointed by Davin Kho.

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me.in url i am just add **&is_developer=1** and base string I am using utf8_encode.

$timestamp = time();

> $path = '/api/v2/auth/access_token/get'; 
> $base = $partnerId.$path.$timestamp;  
> $sign = hash_hmac('sha256',utf8_encode($base), $partnerKey);

> $url  = $host.$path.sprintf("?timestamp=%s&partner_id=%s&sign=%s&is_developer=1'",$timest,$partner_id,$sign);

and in change this CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data, with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, it is always better to include why your answer works and more better if include the source of your answer.